# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ when ,$f(x)=e^{-e^{x}}e^{x}\sin x$ by residues or otherwise

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, residue-calculus, entire-functions

Evaluate improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ .
$$f(x)=e^{-e^{x}}e^{x}\sin x$$

My try-
Can I have a semi circular path from $0$ to $R$ and counterclockwise semi-circle?

Comment: You are correct. Furthermore, $a$ and $b$ can be *any* pair of complex numbers.

Comment: @user1337 Actually I had an improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$. Please tell me about the path of integration if f(z) is entire function.

Comment: Entire functions are typically unbounded (Liouville's theorem), so this improper integral usually diverges.  Do you have a specific $f$ in mind?

Comment: @lisyarus yes my $$f(x)=e^{-e^{x}}e^{x}sin x$$

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks for the edit. Please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral is
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - e^x } e^x \sin xdx} & = \Im \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - e^x } e^x e^{ix} dx}  = \Im \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - e^x } e^{(1 + i)x} dx} \\ & \mathop  = \limits^{t = e^x } \Im \int_1^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} t^i dt}  = \Im \Gamma (1 + i,1) = 0.1866485915\ldots,
\end{align*}
where $\Gamma(a,z)$ is the (upper) incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Thank you so much.